# Learning how to deal with ... in functions in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

This is my function. Basically I want to include a `if else` statement inside it but controlling by the length of the arguments that I use in ...:

This is what Ive tried so far,  and it is wrong:

```
  soma_mtcars<-function(data,...){
    if(length(...) < 2){
     sum_df<- data %>% group_by() %>% summarise(total = sum(disp))
    }
    else(
      sum_df<- data %>% group_by() %>% summarise(total = sum(disp))
    )
  }
```

Of course the problem is in `length(...) < 2`. How can I deal with it?

And I would like to have, for example, outputs for: `soma_mtcars(mtcars,cyl)` and `soma_mtcars(mtcars, cyl, disp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nargs()`, which gives you the *total* number of arguments (i.e. including your `data` argument):

```
soma_mtcars <- function (data, ...) {
    if (nargs() < 3L) { …
}
```

… or you can pass `...` `list`, and get the length of its result:

```
soma_mtcars <- function (data, ...) {
    if (length(list(...)) < 2L) { …
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option its not working for me. Did you try?

Comment: @Laura Yes, it works for me (but you need `list` instead of `c` if you are passing recursive [i.e. list] arguments to the function). But you should use `...length()` as suggested in the other answer. I had forgotten about that function. It’s a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these will return the length of dot dot dot.  The first one does it without evaluating dot dot dot.

```
len_noeval <- function(...) ...length()

len_eval <- function(...) length(list(...))

# test

len_noeval(11, print(12), 13)
## [1] 3

len_eval(11, print(12), 13)
## [1] 12
## [1] 3
```